# Laravel eloquent self many to many relationship with no strict order

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, relationship

I don't know how to form question in correct way and if exist some terminology for this problem.
I have a table of cities and table of connection between cities:

```
city1_name   city2_name
Atlanta      New York
Moscow       Madrid
Atlanta      Madrid
Moscow       Tokyo
Tokyo        Atlanta

etc          etc
```

So connections are not repeatable and are symmetric and if I want to get all connection of one city I can't do like this:

```
$this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'city_city', 'city1_name', 'city2_name);
```

With this approach, for example, for Atlanta it will return New York and Madrid but won't return Tokyo, which I wish to be returned too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I have come to this solution:

```
protected function connections1(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'city_city', 'city1_id', 'city2_id');
}

protected function connections2(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class, 'city_city', 'city2_id', 'city1_id');
}

public function getConnectionsAttribute(){
    $conn1 = $this->connections1;
     foreach ($this->connections2 as $conn){
         $conn1->push($conn);
     }
    return ($conn1);
}


$city = City::find('Atlanta');
$city->connections; //Gives respective objects for New York,Madrid and Tokyo.
```